# Docker getting dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error on installing ubuntu image

Tags: laravel, docker, ubuntu

I just started `Docker` and in the first time i try to install `Laravel` for `Docker` with `Sail`, after running below command i get error and I can't found how can i solve that:

```
./vendor/bin/sail up
```

Error:

```
Fetched 17.2 MB in 1min 33s (184 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following additional packages will be installed:
  dirmngr file git-man gnupg-l10n gnupg-utils gpg gpg-agent gpg-wks-client
  ...
  python3-minimal python3-pkg-resources python3.8 python3.8-minimal
  readline-common xauth xz-utils zlib1g-dev
Suggested packages:
  dbus-user-session libpam-systemd pinentry-gnome3 tor gettext-base
  ...
Preparing to unpack .../03-openssl_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb ...
...
Selecting previously unselected package libkrb5-3:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../22-libkrb5-3_1.17-6ubuntu4.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libkrb5-3:amd64 (1.17-6ubuntu4.1) ...
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 unable to fsync updated status of 'libkrb5-3:amd64': Input/output error
```

this is content of `docker.yml` file which i clone `Laravel` from this url:

```
curl -s https://laravel.build/exampleapp | bash
```

docker.yml:

```
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.0
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.0/app
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            - redis
            - selenium
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
        volumes:
            - 'sailmysql:/var/lib/mysql'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping"]
    redis:
        image: 'redis:alpine'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_REDIS_PORT:-6379}:6379'
        volumes:
            - 'sailredis:/data'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
    meilisearch:
        image: 'getmeili/meilisearch:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MEILISEARCH_PORT:-7700}:7700'
        volumes:
            - 'sailmeilisearch:/data.ms'
        networks:
            - sail
    mailhog:
        image: 'mailhog/mailhog:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_PORT:-1025}:1025'
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_DASHBOARD_PORT:-8025}:8025'
        networks:
            - sail
    selenium:
       image: 'selenium/standalone-chrome'
       volumes:
            - '/dev/shm:/dev/shm'
       networks:
           - sail
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sailmysql:
        driver: local
    sailredis:
        driver: local
    sailmeilisearch:
        driver: local
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing `Dockerfile` as adding `--fix-missing` into this commands, resolve my problem

```yaml
&& apt-get install -y php8.0-cli php8.0-dev \
       php8.0-pgsql php8.0-sqlite3 php8.0-gd \
       php8.0-curl php8.0-memcached \
       php8.0-imap php8.0-mysql php8.0-mbstring \
       php8.0-xml php8.0-zip php8.0-bcmath php8.0-soap \
       php8.0-intl php8.0-readline \
       php8.0-msgpack php8.0-igbinary php8.0-ldap \
       php8.0-redis --fix-missing\
```